# Git: how to go back to a previous commit

Tags: git

I am in this situation in `master`:

```
     --c1--c2--c3--c4
```

I am in `c4`, but I don't like it, I would like go back to `c1` and work on that in master:

```
        ______________   
       /              \
    --c1--c2--c3--c4   c6
```

Please how do I achieve that?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Please check this answer, looks like it's what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this -

```
git checkout c1
```

Return to `master` branch

```
git checkout master
```

`git checkout -`, which will checkout the previous branch or commit that `HEAD` pointed at.

Let me know if it helps.

Thanks!

Comment: `git checkout <commitID>` You can use this to peek at old revision.

Answer (score 5):

An easy way i use to step backwards in a number of steps is `git checkout HEAD~[number]`

If i want to go back for 3 steps, you'll write `git checkout HEAD~3` if you ignore the number then git will assume it's 1 step

Of course you can always just take the hash and checkout to that hash

```
git checkout ABC123
```

Note that you will become in a detached head state, meaning there's no branch pointing to this hash, so you either `git reset` to drop all the other changes and make this commit your latest, or `git branch` to create a new branch name to make sure your commits don't become unreachable.